# How to mark a sound or image/movie ID as asset?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, asset

How do I mark these new ID as assets?

The script converts the selected strips in the sequencer to data-blocks with ID's, but how do I mark the new ID's to assets(so the become visible in the asset browser?)

```
import bpy, os

strips = bpy.context.selected_editable_sequences
strips = sorted(strips, key=lambda strip: strip.frame_final_start)

for sq in strips:

    if sq.type == "SOUND":
        path = bpy.path.abspath(sq.sound.filepath)
        my_sound = bpy.data.sounds.load(path)
        #bpy.ops.asset.mark(my_sound.asset_data)
    if sq.type == "MOVIE":    
        activestrp = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[sq.name]
        mov_path = bpy.path.abspath(activestrp.filepath)
        my_mov = bpy.data.images.load(mov_path)
        #bpy.ops.asset.mark(my_mov.asset_data)
```

Comment: It's in 3.0 alpha. In order to list the case contents in the asset browser, it's necessary to convert it to IDs and mark them as asset. Not sure I understand what you're writing. Maybe I'll have to read it a couple of times.

Comment: There are a few examples of it in use here: https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=asset.mark+bpy&type=Code but that doesn't make the use of bpy.ops.asset.mark anymore clear to me.

Comment: Ok, going by first script snippet in github search link it uses `context.id` which if not set in asset browser, can be passed as a context override to the operator.  Cant test (well could will get back if on right version)  try `bpy.ops.asset.mark({"id" : sq.sound})`  (or build a full override `c = context.copy()` then set id `c["id"] = sq.sound` and then call `bpy.ops.asset.mark(c)`  If a dictionary is the first argument it is treated as a context override (see docs).

Comment: bpy.ops.asset.mark({"id" : sq.sound}) is working. Thank you. What would the attribute be for a movie type?

Comment: Thank you. {"id" : my_mov} is working. Do you want to write a "real" answer? Could be with the movie clip solution, since it is properly better suited for the purpose.

Comment: Ok, done. Rarely answer without testing code. Please check that assumption re `selected_ids` is also  viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Uses the `context.id` member**

As shown in [github search link provided in comments](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=asset.mark+bpy&type=Code) the operator uses the data block referenced by `context.id`

```
import bpy, os

strips = bpy.context.selected_editable_sequences
strips = sorted(strips, key=lambda strip: strip.frame_final_start)

for sq in strips:

    if sq.type == "SOUND":
        path = bpy.path.abspath(sq.sound.filepath)
        my_sound = sq.sound
        bpy.ops.asset.mark({"id" : my_sound})
    if sq.type == "MOVIE":    
        mov_path = bpy.path.abspath(sq.filepath)
        my_mov = bpy.data.movieclips.load(mov_path)
        bpy.ops.asset.mark({"id" : my_mov})
```

To be consistent with other ops that work on context object and all selected, would also assume that multiple datablocks could be set by

```
bpy.ops.asset.mark({"selected_ids" : [my_sound, my_movie_clip]})
```

hence instead of calling operator N times for N individual datablocks, can call operator once.  Logic wise would pre define an empty  list  `datablocks = []` and append each, `datablocks.append(my_sound)` as required, and then `bpy.ops.asset.mark({"selected_ids" : datablocks})`

Comment: This line have disappeared: activestrp = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[sq.name] and for some reason it is bpy.data.movieclips with 's'. :-)

Comment: Cheers, 2 errors is not bad for not testing. Saw no reason to have the `active = long.address.to.same.ref.by.name[foo.name]` forgot to take it out again.  Should be `movieclips` my mistake.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help.